# Copy a value in one cell, based on other cell and structure the data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data sheet, which contains names of people and hours per day that they worked. I need to sum the numbers worked per day and week for each person.
The sheet looks like this

```
  A      B  
Peter  8.000  
Bob    4.000  
Jane   3.000  
Jane   4.000
```

Each person has several entries and my boss wants me to show them on weekly and monthly basis, so he is able to track if someone has done overtime more recently than others.

Comment: How do you know on which date the hours where worked?

Comment: Not sure you need a Macro for this?

Comment: Try to look for `SUMIF` formula

Comment: Isn't this what PivotTables are for?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jmax and KingCronus here. You actually do not need a macro. You can achieve it with a formula.

**NON VBA**

I am assuming that the values are in Col A and Col B.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="Jane")*(B:B))
```

**VBA**

If you still want VBA then you can use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sName As String

    sName = "Jane"

    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=" & _
    Chr(34) & sName & Chr(34) & ")*(B:B))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello guys. Thanks for the tips, but that didn`t work. I am not sure if that makes any difference, but i changed the columns, because those one in the example were fictional. Indeed the sheet is wider than this and it has several columns, like responsible manager and etc, but i don`t think those are important. I evaluated the formula via excel and it gave me FALSE on each step, i also tried to change the formatting of the numeric values, but it didn`t work as well. My  version of excel is 2010, but i am not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: I actually used pivot table, so now i have what i needed. Thank you all.

Comment: I have tested the above formula and the code and it works as expected. If you can show me an exact sample then we can see why is it not working for you. However if you want to stick with Pivot Table then that is also a good idea.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to filter a range with the syntax `A:A="Jane"`. What else I don't know? Do you know where I can find the documentation?